# How to use fontawesome package with article class, using Sharelatex.com?

Tags: article, sharelatex, fontawesome

I'm using the article class, also worth mentioning is that I use Sharelatex.com. I have the compiler set to XeLaTex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter
\end{document}
```

Why is it not working, is it because of Sharelatex? I have also tried to implement this strategy https://coderwall.com/p/r67dyq, but it won't work either.

Comment: You can't. As far as I know, sharelatex.com uses TeX Live 2011 that doesn't (and won't) support `fontawesome`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using LuaLatex compiler? It works for me

Comment: Does ShareLaTeX.com use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: [It does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9CVKH.png)...

Answer (score 0):

Switching to LuaLaTeX works. No trouble at all, although rendering did seem to slow down.

[image: proof.]

Rendering time can be fixed by declaring a method like:

```
DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion, when using pdfLatex use e.g. \faicon{Twitter}. It works for me in sharelatex. And just the fontawesome package is enough for it, no need of fontspec or any other external package.